# Call a functor in Python

Tags: python

Should be easy, but somehow I don't get it. I want to apply a given function. Background is copy a class and applying a given method on the newly created copy.

**Major Edit. Sorry for that.**

```
   import copy
   class A:

       def foo(self,funcName):
           print 'foo'
           funcName()

       def Bar(self):
           print 'Bar'

        def copyApply(self,funcName):
           cpy = copy.copy()
           # apply funcName to cpy??

    a = A()
    func = a.Bar()
    a.foo(func) # output 'Bar'
    b = a.copyApply(foo) # new copy with applied foo
```

Comment: sorry, do you want to call a method on the copy?

Comment: yes. I can can't use getattr() because funcName is not the name of the function.

Comment: Should that be `cpy = copy.copy(self)`? What are you copying?

Comment: @RParadox you want to use `A.foo` to pass as the function argument then. see my (and Eric's) answer(s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that your `A.foo` does not take the *name* of a function, but the function itself.

```
class A:
   def bar(self):
       print 'Bar'

   def apply(self, func):
       func()  # call it like any other function

   def copyApply(self, func):
       cpy = copy.copy(self)
       func(cpy)  # cpy becomes the self parameter

a = A()
func = a.bar  # don't call the function yet

a.apply(func)       # call the bound method `a.bar`
a.apply(a.bar)      # same as the line above
a.copyApply(A.bar)  # call the unbound method `A.bar` on a new `A`
```

In python, `a.foo()` is the same as `A.foo(a)`, where `a` is of type `A`. Therefore, your `copyApply` method takes the *unbound* bar method as its argument, whereas `foo` takes a *bound* method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a method on a copy of the instance

```
class A (object):
    def foo(self):
        pass

    def copyApply(self,func):
        cpy = copy.copy(self)
        func(cpy)
```

and call it like so

```
a = A()
a.copyApply(A.foo)
```

note I am getting the method `foo` from the class, not the instance, as `A.foo` expects an instance of `A` as the first argument, and `a.foo` takes no arguments.